# Autocomplete in Hibernate 3, no JTA, no EJB, no JPA

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, glassfish-4, hibernate3

As I read in the PrimeFaces showcase, a converter is needed for my autoComplete to work, so I did as follows:

```
<p:autoComplete id="ListaInst"
    emptyMessage="Nenhuma instituição encontrada."
    value="#{InstituicaoController.inst1}"
    completeMethod="#{InstituicaoController.getInstituicoesLike}"
    var="i"
    itemLabel="#{i.inst_nome}"
    itemValue="#{i}"
    converter="instituicaoConverter"
    required="true"
    style="width: 200px;font-family: monospace; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 4px;" />
```

The managed bean method:

```
public Collection<Instituicao> getInstituicoesLike(String searchKeyword) {
    InstituicaoDao dao = new InstituicaoDao();
    Collection<Instituicao> instituicoes = dao.getInstituicoesLike(searchKeyword);
    return instituicoes;
}
```

The DAO method:

```
public Collection<Instituicao> getInstituicoesLike(String searchKeyword) {
    Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        ss.beginTransaction();
        List instituicoes = ss.createCriteria(Instituicao.class).add(Restrictions.like("inst_nome", searchKeyword)).list();
        ss.beginTransaction().commit();
        ss.close();
        ss.clear();
        return instituicoes;
    } catch(HibernateException e) {
        ss.getTransaction().rollback();
        ss.close();
        ss.clear();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know it's better to use JTA, JPA 2.1, JSF 2.2, EJB 3.1 and Hibernate 4.3.4 (and it worked perfectly using these), but I don't know if it would be acceptable in the project I'm working on. Narrow minded developers don't want to "learn everything again" and think code like `this.manager.persist(entity)` is worse than that boilerplate above.

P.S.: Converter code:

```
package br.com.solidaria.converters;

import br.com.solidaria.dao.InstituicaoDao;
import br.com.solidaria.model.Instituicao;

import javax.faces.component.*;
import javax.faces.context.*;
import javax.faces.convert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Rodrigo Sieja Bertin
 */
@FacesConverter(forClass = Instituicao.class, value = "instituicaoConverter")
public class InstituicaoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        InstituicaoDao dao = new InstituicaoDao();
        Instituicao i = InstituicaoDao.getById(Integer.parseInt(value));
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    Instituicao i = (Instituicao) value;
        return String.valueOf(i.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your exact problem?

Comment: Autocomplete can't find anything

Comment: javax.el.ELException: /cadAcao.xhtml @84,122 value="#{AcaoController.listUserRH}": org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

Comment: In your DAO method you begin the transaction twice.

Comment: Changed beginTransaction().commit() to getTransaction().commit() and TransactionException is gone; then changed getCurrentSession() to openSession() and get rid of SessionException; finally, changed the query line to List instituicoes = ss.createCriteria(Instituicao.class).add(Restrictions.like("inst_nome", searchKeyword, MatchMode.START).ignoreCase()).list(); and problem is solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Xtreme Biker comment, changed `ss.beginTransaction().commit()` to `ss.getTransaction().commit()` and `TransactionException` is gone.

Changed `getCurrentSession()` to `openSession()` to get rid of `SessionException`.

Finally, changed the query line to `List instituicoes = ss.createCriteria(Instituicao.class).add(Restrictions.like("inst_nome", searchKeyword, MatchMode.START).ignoreCase()).list();` and problem is solved.